# Vue 3.0 Use Var as Key

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, object, variables

I try my best to understand this issue:

I can make a v-for like so:

```
<div v-for="playlistItem of playlists.PLDk0_ZYOcqxEq5ZxXAI5FiVL79hk2oSua.items">
        {{playlistItem.snippet.title}}
      </div>
```

You can see that i have a Playlist ID is used as key in the playlists object - this is working fine.

When i try to do this:

```
 <div v-for="playlist of channel.items" :key="playlist.id">
  <div v-if="playlist.contentDetails.itemCount && playlist.status.privacyStatus === 'public'">
    <div>{{playlist.snippet.title}}</div>
    <div>{{playlist.id}}</div>
    <div>
      <div class="content">Content:</div>
      <div v-for="playlistItem of playlists[playlist.id].items">
        {{playlistItem.snippet.title}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

the application blocks and tells me that "Cannot read property 'items' of undefined".

{{playlist.id}} gives me the searched playlist and when i do this:
**{{playlists[playlist.id]}} it shows me the object on the page.**

But this {{playlists[playlist.id].items}} cannot be used so what i am missing?

**Background:**

```
<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import channel from '@/../public/cache/channel.json'
import playlists from '@/../public/cache/playlists/'

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    channel, playlists
  },
  data(){
    //console.log(channel)
    console.log(playlists)
    return{
      channel, playlists
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

channel contains youtube channel data in json and for the playlists i have the playlists object like so:

```
{
    "PLDk0_ZYOcqxEqFirstKey" : {"kind":"","etag:"","items":[...]},
    "PLDk0_ZYOcqxEqanotherKey" : {"kind":"","etag:"","items":[...]},
}
```

So in fact i try to get from the playlists object the object with the ID of this for loop to loop then through its items:
playlist."variableIdFormParentLoop".items

Code Sandbox Link : [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-variables-as-key-timfk?file=/src/App.vue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the playlist IDs from `channel.items[]` are missing from `playlists`, so when those IDs are encountered, `playlists[playlist.id]` is `undefined`, leading to the error you observed.

One solution is to conditionally render the playlist data based on `playlists[playlist.id]`:

```html
<template v-if="playlists[playlist.id]">
  <div class="content">Content:</div>
  <div v-for="playlistItem of playlists[playlist.id].items" :key="playlistItem.snippet.id">
    {{playlistItem.snippet.title}}
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-variables-as-key-forked-59b3y?file=/src/App.vue:339-667)